# Matching two vectors with same elements but not ordered the same

Tags: clips

I'm trying to write a general rule that will activate when two facts like these two are present:

(Vector v1 3 4 5)
(Vector v2 1 3 10 15 5 2 4)

(Elements 4 5 3)

So, my problem is that I don't know how to match ALL the unordered elements in the vector, in order to fire the rule.

I want the rule to activate only when ALL the elements from Elements are present, not taking in consideration if they follow the same order.

I haven't been able to achieve it, so I ask for help.

Examples of rules not doing what I want:

```
(defrule Equal

    (Elements $?x)

    (Vector ?name $?y)

    (test (member$ $?x $?y))

    =>

    (printout t ?name crlf)
)
```

*The problem of this one is that it fires when both are blank, and mainly when a single member of ?x is contained in ?y, but I want the rule to fire when ALL elements in ?x are in ?y.

I tried using this simplier one too:

```
(defrule Equal

    (Elements $? $?x $?)

    (Vector ?name $? $?y $?)

    =>

    (printout t ?name crlf)
)
```

But in this case the rule only activates when the elements are exactly the same and ordered in the same way, but I want to have the flexibility of elements not having to be ordered exactly as they appear in the vector.

Comment: Could you show your current code?

Comment: I've added to the main post some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **subsetp** function rather than **member$**:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 4/1/19)
CLIPS> 
(defrule equal
   (elements $?elements)
   (test (> (length$ ?elements) 0))
   (vector ?name $?values)
   (test (subsetp ?elements ?values))
   =>
   (printout t ?name crlf))
CLIPS> 
(assert (vector v1 3 4 5)
        (vector v2 1 3 10 15 5 2 4)
        (vector v3 4 5 7 2)
        (elements 4 5 3))
<Fact-4>
CLIPS> 
(agenda)
0      equal: f-4,f-2
0      equal: f-4,f-1
For a total of 2 activations.
CLIPS> (run)
v2
v1
CLIPS>
```

You can also do it this way without a function call:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defrule equal
   (elements ? $?)
   (vector ?name $?list)
   (forall (elements $? ?v $?)
           (vector ?name $? ?v $?))
   =>
   (printout t ?name crlf))
CLIPS> 
(assert (vector v1 3 4 5)
        (vector v2 1 3 10 15 5 2 4)
        (vector v3 4 5 7 2)
        (elements 4 5 3))
<Fact-4>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      equal: f-4,f-2,*
0      equal: f-4,f-1,*
For a total of 2 activations.
CLIPS> (run)
v2
v1
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary, it solved my problem. But now I have another doubt.

Is it possible to the same, but in this case, to match a multifield slot of a template? 

So, I have my elements vector, and I want to match the asserts based on a template whose multifield values contain ALL the elements of the vector elements.

Comment: Yes. An ordered fact is internally represented as a deftemplate fact with a single implied multifield slot, so if you define your deftemplate as (deftemplate vector (slot name) (multislot values)), you could change a pattern such as (vector ?name $?list) to (vector (name ?name) (values $?list))